# Removing object properties with empty values from JS object

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to loop over an object and remove properties where the value matches a certain condition?
In this case, I want to remove any properties that have no value.

Here is what I have:

```
var user = { first : 'John', last : 'Doe', city : 'Boston', state : 'MA', zip : '', birthdate : ''}

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(user)){
  if(!value){
    delete user.key;
   }
 });
```

The code is detecting an empty value, but the delete function is not working;

Thanks!

Comment: is it safe to delete a property while iterating over them ?

Comment: @Pierre OP is iterating over the return value of `Object.entries()` not the object itself

Comment: @Andreas : that's right, shouldn't be a problem

Comment: try this: delete user[key];     https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-yonath-crtit

Comment: `key` has the name of the property. You have to use bracket notation to access the property with that name -> `user[key]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, try like so:

```js
var user = { first : 'John', last : 'Doe', city : 'Boston', state : 'MA', zip : '', birthdate : ''};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(user)) {
  if(value.length <= 0) {
      delete user[key]
  }
}
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Reflect.deleteProperty(user, key);`

you can use something like this